# Button in Activity doesn't work after Fragment starts

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, fragment

I am a newbie in Android programming and I have this problem:

In this simple example, when I click on start button, I run a fragment.  When I click on alarm button, I write in a log file.

Now, if I click first the start button, later the alarm button don't run.  I think the problem is the fragment don't leave the interaction with user. Can you help me? 
best regads
A.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final String FRAG1_TAG = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName() +".fragment1";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.i("exemple", "start button Start !!!!!!");
            goFragment();

        }
    }); 
    Button buttonAllarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAllarm);
    buttonAllarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {            
        Log.i("exemple", "start button allarm !!!!!!");
        }// fine onClick    
    });// fine onClickListner
}

void goFragment() {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction xact = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (null == fm.findFragmentByTag(FRAG1_TAG)) {
        xact.replace(android.R.id.content, new ListFramment(), FRAG1_TAG);
         xact.addToBackStack (null);   // questo serve devi metterlo
            xact.commit();
    }
}
```

this is the fragment

```
      public class ListFramment extends ListFragment {
       // onCreate     
        @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    AppLog.logString("Parte onCreateView");
    return view;
}   

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    AppLog.logString("Parte onActivityCreated");
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();

    String[] from = { "name", "purpose" };
    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    list.add(putData("Android", "Mobile"));
    list.add(putData("iPhone", "iPhone"));
    return list;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private HashMap<String, String> putData(String name, String purpose) {
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("name", name);
    item.put("purpose", purpose);
    return item;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
AppLog.logString("Parte onCreateView");
return view;
}
```

Your Fragment is inflating the same layout as the Activity that created it.  But the Fragment does not have any onClickListeners.  I suspect that the Fragment layout is covering up the Activity layout, duplicating it exactly, with non-functional buttons.  That would explain why the button click works only the first time.

It would be normal for the Fragment to have its own layout, different from the Activity.

Comment: thanks for your response, in this link you can see xml file pastebin.com/jcPW4dUT    i have this idea, i use a fragment without layout, this fragment  elaborate the data and later give this data to a parcellable class where i link to the adapter for a listview presente in xml file .  Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: It's fine to make a Fragment without a Layout, but that's not what you did in the code quoted above.  For the case that you just described, I think what you want is a ListFragment and a ContentProvider.

Comment: sparky thanks for your response, i am a newbie in android programming, now i upgrade the project whit your idea thx.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing your layout file does not help. But I suspect it got nothing to do with fragments.

Comment: I downvoted because I believe this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: thanks for your response,in this link you can see xml file http://pastebin.com/jcPW4dUT